# Clearing a request header

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a request header with the name "USER". I can get it in my servlet filter by

```
request.getHeader("USER")
```

Is it possible to clear this value?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset some request header value. But, you can write a request wrapper using a filter which returns `null` if the header name is `USER`

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. This header value is being accessed by a single sign on agent. I was checking if there is any way to clear is header value so that the SSO agent would prompt the user for user id / password.